# Google OR Tools does not return solution if First solution strategy = SAVINGS

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm currently learning on how to use Google OR-Tools, specifically on the routing problem. I want to try to use Clarke and Wright Savings Algorithm by setting the first solution strategy equals SAVINGS as we can see below

`search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = ( routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.SAVINGS)`

but when i try executing the program, it returns nothing. what did i do wrong?

my code is exactly like the code here https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem with ortools when I use the SAVINGS algorithm, have you found any relevant way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First solutions heuristics are exactly that, heuristics. They cannot fail on a pure problem.

When adding constraints, they all have blind spots and can fail to find a solution, especially if constraints are tight.

The best solution is to:

- relax time windows with soft constraints
- allow node yo be optional

This way, the solver usually find a first solution, albeit a bad one, and then can use LS to improve it.

Comment: in this problem, i use CVRP which has no time windows and every node should be visited. is there any other solution that i can use to obtain a solution with savings algorithm? thanks

Comment: Make node optional with a high penalty. This way, the solver will work hard to try to have them all performed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [Parallel Savings](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/a64588df8e57a99a79d3ed4d727c3320f1f1d0fa/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.proto#L69) can find the solution. The default is the Sequential version.

```
search_parameters.savings_parallel_routes = True
```